# PHP and SQL: code is really slow

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
$unique = array();
$sql = "SELECT ID, TitleName, ArtistDisplayName, Mix FROM values_to_insert as A
        WHERE A.ID = ";

//Get a single row from our data that needs to be inserted...
while($result = $conn->query(($sql. $count)))
{

    //Get the $data of the single row query for inserting.
    $data = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
    $count++;

    //SQL to get a match of the single row of $data we just fetched...
    $get_match = "SELECT TitleName_ti, Artist_ti, RemixName_ti from titles as B
                    Where B.TitleName_ti = '$data[1]'
                    and B.Artist_ti = '$data[2]'
                    and B.RemixName_ti = '$data[3]' 
                    LIMIT 1";

    //If this query returns a match, then push this data to our $unique value array.
    if(!$result = $conn->query($get_match))
    {
        //If this data has been pushed already, (since our data includes repeats), then don't 
        //put a repeat of the data into our unique array. Else, push the data.
        if(!in_array($unique, $data))
        {
            echo 'Pushed to array: ' . $data[0] . "---" . $data[1] . "</br>";
            array_push($unique, $data);
        }
        else
            echo'Nothing pushed... </br>';
    }
}
```

This has taken 5+ minutes and nothing has even printed to screen. I'm curious as to what is eating up so much time and possibly an alternative method or function for whatever it is taking all this time up. I guess some pointers in the right direction would be great.

This code basically gets all rows, one at a time, of table 'A'. Checks if there is a match in table 'B', and if there is, then I don't want that $data, but if there isn't,  I then check whether or not the data itself is a repeat because my table 'A' has some repeat values.

Table A has 60,000 rows
Table B has 200,000 rows

Comment: `WHERE A.ID = ";` that for one thing and if it's your actual code, should be throwing you an error, so check for errors and make sure your tables are properly indexed. This I don't understand though `($sql. $count)`.

Comment: If you don't have any indexes on Table B, then you're searching 12000000000 rows.

Comment: Well... you are nesting two queries and by your values you are doing 60000 x 200000 queries... Sure, it will be slow. You should combine both queries in one. Well, you must. JOIN is your friend.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I do that so i can increment the ID and then concatenate the $sql statement with $count. so it becomes WHERE A.ID = (1, 2, 3...etc)"

Comment: As an aside, note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is a fairly meaningless concept.

Comment: @DJSweetness ah, I understand.

Comment: @Dez So, essentially you're saying JOIN the two tables WHERE the 3 values are equal? How would I get values that are not equal with JOIN?

Comment: @DJSweetness However `WHERE A.ID = (1, 2, 3...etc)` aren't you looking for `IN()` or a `FIND_IN_SET()` here? I am questioning the `=` here. Unless there's something I'm not catching *lol*.

Comment: @Strawberry Doesn't LIMIT just ensure that the query doesn't return an enormous amount of data? If table A has 10 values that are all the same (for whatever reason), then it normally would return 10 values, but LIMIT would limit it to 1, no?

Comment: Yes, but which one? If you don't care, then that's fine - but 'not caring' (or apparently not caring) can be symptomatic of flawed design.

Comment: You appear to repeatedly do the first query, get the first row and then do the query again. You need to do the query once, and then for the loop get each row. You change the value, but what values of a.id are you expecting to match on? You are just doing the query for everything from (probably) 1.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm just trying to get row by row of data from table A with that query. So, that query returns row 1 and then it loops and returns row 2 and so on. I'm not really familiar with IN() or FIND_IN_SET(). I'm kind of new to the sql game.

Comment: JOINs is the concept with which you need to familiarise yourself. Never execute a query inside a loop (except where using bound parameters)

Comment: You also check that the 2nd query DOESN'T get a match

Comment: @Strawberry Well, for the first query, I guess it is kind of meaningless since I'm returning a row with an ID, so no matter what, since ID is a key, it will return only one row. However, the second query, I just need to check if there is a match because if there is, then I know the row from the first query is not unique and I shouldn't insert it. So, I don't care about the value returned from the second query.

Comment: @Kickstart I'm expecting the incrementing count, so 1 to however many IDs in Table A until there are no more. The second query: I do that because if there is a match, then I don't want the $data values, but if there is not a match, then I know I can insert $data into Table B later on in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Queries within queries are rarely a good idea

But there appear to be multiple issues with your script. It might be easier to just do the whole lot in SQL and push the results to the array each time. SQL can remove the duplicates:-

```
<?php 

$unique = array();
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT A.ID, 
                A.TitleName, 
                A.ArtistDisplayName, 
                A.Mix 
        FROM values_to_insert as A
        LEFT OUTER JOIN titles as B
        ON B.TitleName_ti = A.ID
        and B.Artist_ti = A.TitleName
        and B.RemixName_ti = A.ArtistDisplayName
        WHERE B.TitleName_ti IS NULL
        ORDER BY a.ID";

if($result = $conn->query(($sql)))
{
    //Get the $data of the single row query for inserting.
    while($data = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
    {
        array_push($unique, $data);
    }
}
```

As to your original query.

You have a count (I presume it is initialised to 0, but if a character then that will do odd things), and get the records with that value. If the first id was 1,000,000,000 then you have done 1b queries before you ever find a record to process. You can just get all the rows in ID order anyway by removing the WHERE clause and ordering by ID.

You then just get a single record from a 2nd query where the details match, but only process them if no record is found. You do not use any of the values that are returned. You can do this by doing a LEFT OUTER JOIN to get matches, and checking that there was no match in the WHERE clause.

*EDIT - as you have pointed out, the fields you appear to be using to match the records do not appear to logically match. I have used them as you did but I expect you really want to match B.TitleName_ti to A.TitleName, B.Artist_ti to A.ArtistDisplayName and B.RemixName_ti to A.Mix*

Comment: Your B.TitleName_ti = A.ID are mismatched?

Comment: The titleName and ID are never going to be equal.

Comment: @DJSweetness - probably very true, but that is the way to original posters query matched things up.